# iPhone 11 doesn’t display wallpaper with same colors/contrast as preview

Tags: iphone, ios, wallpaper

The wallpapers on my iPhone 11 (iOS 13.3) appear washed out (low contrast) compared to the same wallpapers displayed in preview mode `Settings > Wallpaper`.

I’ve played with all settings in `Settings > Display and Brightness`, including “True Tone”. However, they don’t make the wallpapers appear with the same color saturation as in preview mode.

I’ve included two screenshots of the wallpaper appearances. Any ideas of how to make the wallpapers appear as-in preview mode?

**Wallpaper preview:**
[image]

**Actual wallpaper:**
[image]

Comment: Check this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250663656